# How to access photos on disk image from "Photos"

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

With the iPhotos app on my Mac Mini I was able to access a specially created disk image for all my photos.  I have upgraded to Yosemite and now iPhotos reports it is no longer valid and I must use Photos.  The issue is that Photos refuses to import.  How can I access the content of my disk image from Photos?
If I choose to "Show Package Contents" on the image I can browse through the "Masters" folder so I see everything is fine.  As well, "Verify Disk" reports everything is fine.

I did try to follow the instructions here [How to migrate from iPhoto to Photos](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/04/09/migrate-iphoto-library-photos-app/) but it just reports that the library could not be opened.

Mac newbie here so any directions are helpful.

Comment: Why do you have it in a disk image?

Comment: My guess is it's not a .dmg file, it's a Library package file - judging by "Show Package Contents".  What error message are you getting, & at what point in the import?